# Calling a different endpoint from the same running web service in Tornado Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tornado

I have two endpoints in the same web service and one should call the second one. But because the first one is not yet finished, the second one is not called. Below is the demonstration of what I need to achieve.

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import tornado.escape
import time
import requests
import itertools

from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry

class SampleApi1(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        print("1")
        response = requests.post("http://localhost:5000/test2/")
        self.write(response)

class SampleApi2(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        print("2")
        self.write({"key": "value"})

def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([(r"/test1/", SampleApi1),
                                    (r"/test2/", SampleApi2)])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(5000)
    print("Listening on port 5000")
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

`SampleApi1` calls `SampleApi2` but `SampleApi2` is not being called since `SampleApi1` is not yet done. I've read `gen.coroutines` but it didn't work. I don't need to call `SampleApi2` in parallel, I just need to call it from `SampleApi1`. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Wrap the functionality into a function and call it in `SampleApi1`.

Comment: Sadly it can be called independently so I cannot do that

Comment: Um, I don't understand? It surely can be called independently, you just need to also call the wrapped function in `SampleApi2`.

Comment: If you just want some data from other handler, why not extract that code in a common function and call that function from your handlers. Making HTTP requests internally is inefficient. And upon that, `requests` library is not asynchronous; it will block the server.

Answer (score 1):

Tornado is an asynchronous framework, but the `requests` library is synchronous and blocking (see the [tornado user's guide](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/async.html) for more on these concepts). You shouldn't use `requests` in Tornado applications because it blocks the main thread. Instead, use Tornado's own `AsyncHTTPClient` (or another async http client like `aiohttp`):

```
async def post(self):
    print("1")
    client = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
    response = await client.fetch("http://localhost:5000/test2", method="POST", body=b"")
    self.write(response)
```